# Google Appscript Autoresize Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I have here a web application which is supposed to display results according to the data inputed in the first input box. How can I make the text area field auto resizing according to the result given by the search.
[image]

here is the link to my appscript.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyaLumisl19chrp92CLOXnKzYJoCva_f0-nSVpSGgifMM092boz7b_Dqy-Usdkev_d-6g/exec

And here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
 <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdDdxnTkS7jTWo53PCv0SeWQUtyTPEdy1Af_HJyd8ybOUdx9g/formResponse">

     <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. Input ang PT No. or PawnTicket No. makikita po ito sa inyong resibo Ex. 18069.</span>
        <input type="text" id="zip" minlength="5" minlength="6" name="entry.622619968" placeholder="Pawnticket Number" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Pls. Check 5-6 Digits po dapat ang Pawn Ticket No.')"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required="">
      </div>
      <textarea id="est" class="validate" disabled></textarea>
      <br>

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input your name </span>
        <input type="text" name="entry.1473350596" placeholder="Input Your Name" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' required="">
      </div>
      <br>

      
      <div class="form-element">
        <span>C. Input your cellphone number.</span>
        <input type="tel" name="entry.741783283" placeholder="Input CP Number" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{11}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Pls. Check 11 Digits po dapat ang CP No.')"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  

    
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
      <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean auto resizing the text box? Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What do you mean "the result given by the search", how can we reproduce this?

Comment: hi sir, the app script was in the link. when input this : 16776hs (value in the spreadsheet) on the first input field, the result was displayed in a text box.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) tag you would have to [style it using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_with_css).